# Find frame base and variable locations using DWARF version 4

Tags: linux, elf, dwarf

I'm following [Eli Bendersky's blog on parsing the DWARF debug information](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information). He shows an example of parsing the binary with DWARF version 2 in his blog. The **frame base of a function** (further used for retrieving local variables) can be retrieved from the `location list`:

```
<1><71>: Abbrev Number: 5 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <72>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <73>   DW_AT_name        : (...): do_stuff
    <77>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <78>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 4
    <79>   DW_AT_prototyped  : 1
    <7a>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x8048604
    <7e>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x804863e
    <82>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 0x0      (location list)
    <86>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0xb3>
...
$ objdump --dwarf=loc tracedprog2
Contents of the .debug_loc section:

    Offset   Begin    End      Expression
    00000000 08048604 08048605 (DW_OP_breg4: 4 )
    00000000 08048605 08048607 (DW_OP_breg4: 8 )
    00000000 08048607 0804863e (DW_OP_breg5: 8 )
```

However, I find in DWARF version 4 there is no such `.debug_loc` section. Here is the function info on my machine:

```
<1><300>: Abbrev Number: 17 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <301>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <301>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x1e0): do_stuff
    <305>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <306>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 3
    <307>   DW_AT_decl_column : 6
    <308>   DW_AT_prototyped  : 1
    <308>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x1149
    <310>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x47
    <318>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 1 byte block: 9c        (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)
    <31a>   DW_AT_GNU_all_tail_call_sites: 1
```

Line <318> indicates the frame base is `1 byte block: 9c (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)`. Any idea how to find the frame base for the DWARF v4 binaries?

---

Update based on @Employed Russian's answer:
The frame_base of a subprogram seems to point to the Canonical Frame Address (CFA), which is the RBP value before the call instruction.

```
 <2><329>: Abbrev Number: 19 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <32a>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x7d): my_local
    <32e>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <32f>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 5
    <330>   DW_AT_decl_column : 9
    <331>   DW_AT_type        : <0x65>
    <335>   DW_AT_location    : 2 byte block: 91 6c     (DW_OP_fbreg: -20)
```

So a local variable (`my_local` in the above example) can be located by the CFA using this calculation: `&my_local` = `CFA` - 20 = (`current RBP` + 16) - 20 = `current RBP` - 4.
Verify it by checking the assembly:

```
void do_stuff(int my_arg)
{
    1149:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    114d:   55                      push   %rbp
    114e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1151:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
    1155:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
    int my_local = my_arg + 2;
    1158:   8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
    115b:   83 c0 02                add    $0x2,%eax
    115e:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
```

`my_local` is at `-0x4(%rbp)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't about `DWARFv2` vs. `DWARFv4` -- using either version the compiler may chose to use or not use location lists. Your compiler chose not to.

> Any idea how to find the frame base for the DWARF v4 binaries?

It tells you right there: use the `CFA` pseudo-register, also known as "canonical frame address".

That "imaginary" register has the same value that `%rsp` had just before the current function was called. That is, current function's return address is always stored at `CFA+0`, and `%rsp == CFA+8` on entry into the function.

If the function uses frame pointer, then previous value of `%rbp` is usually stored at `CFA+8`.

More info [here](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2017/01/18/cfi.html).

Comment: Just checked the variable address using CFA, it matches the offset from the assembly.

Comment: BTW, what is the meaning of the code after the locations, like `2 byte block: 91 6c`, or `1 byte block: 9c`?